# Creating a model object in django using my uploaded file corrupts the file

Tags: python, django, post, django-models, django-rest-framework

I have a model which uploads a file from an ImageField. In my view I get this value from a jpg file I get via POST.

View code:

```
 if request.method == "POST":

        errorID = request.POST.get("errorid")
        emailAddress = request.POST.get("toemail")
        imageAttach = request.FILES['snapshot']
        phoneNum = request.POST.get("number")
        timeStamp = datetime.now()
        imageAttach.name = str(errorID) + '.jpg'
        ticket = UserTicket.create(errorID, emailAddress, phoneNum, imageAttach, timeStamp)
        ticket.save()
```

Model Code:

```
class UserTicket(models.Model):
    ErrorID = models.CharField(max_length=255, primary_key=True, unique=True, db_column='Error ID')
    EmailAddress = models.CharField(max_length=255, db_column='Email Address', blank=True)
    PhoneNumber = models.CharField(max_length=255, db_column='Phone Number', blank=True)
    Snapshot = models.ImageField(upload_to='images', blank=True, null = True, db_column='Image')
    Timestamp = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, db_column='Date/Time Submitted')

    @classmethod
    def create(cls, eID, eAddress, pNumber, img, tStamp):

        userTicket = cls( ErrorID = eID, EmailAddress = eAddress, PhoneNumber = pNumber, Snapshot = img, Timestamp = tStamp)
        return userTicket
```

I have this data set to send out an email with the details in UserTicket, with the image file as an attachment. For some reason when I send the data direct from the POST, the image attachment is perfect. But when I try to send the data after I've created the object, the file is 200 bytes and windows doesn't know what to do with the file.

**EDIT** to clarify... this code works just fine:

```
       # ticket = UserTicket.create(errorID, emailAddress, phoneNum, imageAttach, timeStamp)
       # ticket.save()

        email = EmailMessage(
        'ERROR ID: {}'.format(errorID),
        'Problem details here. Image attached. Name is {}'.format(imageAttach.name),
        '*****@****.com',
        ['{}'.format(emailAddress)],
        )

        email.attach(imageAttach.name, imageAttach.read(), imageAttach.content_type)

        email.send()
```

But this code gives me a 200 byte unknown file as the attachment:

```
            ticket = UserTicket.create(errorID, emailAddress, phoneNum, imageAttach, timeStamp)
            ticket.save()

            email = EmailMessage(
            'ERROR ID: {}'.format(errorID),
            'Problem details here. Image attached. Name is {}'.format(imageAttach.name),
            '*****@****.com',
            ['{}'.format(emailAddress)],
            )

            email.attach(imageAttach.name, imageAttach.read(), imageAttach.content_type)

            email.send()
```

Note - I'd change the values from imageAttach etc to ticket.Snapshot but this was just to demonstrate that the imageAttach value also doesn't work now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution. Turns out it was a stupid oversight but I also learned a lesson here.

The solution was just to use `ticket.Snapshot` after creating the object. I don't know how I missed that. I had convinced myself I'd already tested that and then tried the `imageAttach` variable instead.

The lesson here is that it went wrong when I tried to use my original variable after passing it into `UserTicket`. Must be due to the way parameter passing works in Python? Perhaps anyone more in the know can add to this answer.